# How Can I Save A Class Diagram In Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, class-diagram

I discovered that in Intellij I can create nice class diagrams by going to New > Diagram > Java Class Diagram.  I can do everything that I want to do, except figure out how to save the diagram after I'm done.  When I create a diagram, save it, shut down Intellij, and then start it up again, I see that the diagram that I had just "saved" has reverted to a generic window displaying all of the packages in my project.  I realize that I can save the diagam in a PNG format, but I don't want to do that.  I want to be able to save it in an editable format?  Thoughts?

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79046.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't seem to even save it by clicking on the floppy disk save icon.  I click it and nothing happens.  Is there another save button somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The top left save disk does nothing.  The right save disk will actually save the diagram.

[image: Screen shot showing which save disk to click]

Comment: imo, this is a usability flaw

Answer (score 2):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15**

A general method (that works when you can't find/remember something)

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (or go to Help > Find Action)
- type "Save d" (or just "dia")

  [image: Save diagram]
- double click on the "Save diagram" row
- select the path where you want to save it > OK

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2022

Click this icon [image: export] or right-click a blank spot on the diagram and select `Export Diagram`. Click `Export to File` then pick your format.